LIFFブラウザ内に表示した注文ページからPayPayアプリで決済した後、LIFFブラウザ内に戻り注文完了ページを表示したい
お世話になっております。
ご意見をいただけたら幸いでございます。
タイトルの通り、LIFFブラウザ内に表示した注文ページから
PayPayアプリで決済した後、LIFFブラウザ内に戻り注文完了ページを表示したいと
考えているのですが、現状LIFFブラウザではなく、スマートフォンの標準ブラウザ
(iPhoneでしたらSafari等)が起動し、こちらに注文完了ページを表示してしまいます。
PayPay決済においては、ソフトバンクペイメントサービス(以下、SBPS)を利用しています。
詳細を出せず、ご回答いただくのは難しいと思いますが、
どのあたりが怪しいとか、こうしたら？みたいな案等をいただけると大変助かります。
個人的には決済終了時にSBPSのURLを経由している為、
その部分がうまくLIFFブラウザに戻せていない原因かな…と考えているのですが、
その部分の切り分けもうまくいっていない状況です。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。
